# Netbeans events: variable evt is never read

Tags: java, netbeans

Using NetBeans, I have created a Java program with a graphical interface. I have placed grapichal objects (such as buttons etc.), and have created events on them (actionPerformed). NetBeans automatically creates the methods associated with this events, like this:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Using later versions of NetBeans (I'm now working with 12.2), on each of this methods there is this warning: "variable evt is never read". How can i turn off this stupid warning?

I dont't want to completely disable the "unused element" warning, only this specifical one. Is there a way to do it?

In older versions of NetBeans this warning was never shown, I cannot understand why they changed it... it's so annoying

Comment: Why not just remove the parameter if you're not using it?

Comment: You cannot modify the code generated by NetBeans (it's in a grey area). Or can you somehow?